# Problema para inserir dados de uma tabela em outra no java com banco de dados

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, maven

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Estou fazendo um projeto para a faculdade, ele possui 3 classes, Admin, Cards, Specs.
Na classe Specs contem String Atk, String def, String hp.

Estou usando o JPA com o Hibernate no java.

Basicamente preciso de uma forma de pegar 1 linha da tabela Specs, e salvar na tabela Cards.
Ja tentei de todas as formas e não consigo.

```
type here
```

Tentei os seguinte códigos:

```
spec.find(Long.valueOf(2)); //estou fazendo a pesquisa de uma linha da tablea Specs pelo id

cartas.setCardName(specs.getCardName()); 
cartas.setAtk(specs.getAtk());
cartas.setDef(specs.getDef());
cartas.setHp(specs.getHp());
carta.salvar(cartas);
```

Classe Specs:
@Entity
@Table(name="tb_specs")
public class Specs {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idSpec;

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 20)
 String cardName;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4,name = "cardAtk")
private String atk;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4,name = "cardHP")
private String hp;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4, name = "cardDef")
private String def;
```

//    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "tb_specs") Teste
//    private List cards;

```
public Specs(String cardName, String atk, String def,String hp){
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def = def;  
    this.hp = hp;
}
public Specs(){
}

public Long getId(){
    return this.idSpec;
}

public void setId(Long id){
    this.idSpec = id;
}

public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
}

public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
} 

public String getAtk() {
    return atk;
}

public void setAtk(String atk) {
    this.atk = atk;
}

public String getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public void setHp(String hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}

public String getDef() {
    return def;
}

public void setDef(String def) {
    this.def = def;
}
```

}

Classe Cards:

@Entity
@Table(name="tb_cards")

public class Cards /*extends Specs*/ {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long idCards;

```
@Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 20)
 String cardName;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4,name = "cardAtk")
private String atk;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4,name = "cardHP")
private String hp;

@Column(nullable = false, unique = false, precision = 4, name = "cardDef")
private String def;

public Cards(String cardName, String atk, String def,String hp){
    this.cardName = cardName;
    this.atk = atk;
    this.def = def;  
    this.hp = hp;
}

@ManyToOne
private Specs specs;

@ManyToOne
private Admin admin;


public Cards(){
}

public Long getId(){
    return this.idCards;
}

public String getCardName() {
    return cardName;
}

public void setCardName(String cardName) {
    this.cardName = cardName;
} 

public String getAtk() {
    return atk;
}

public void setAtk(String atk) {
    this.atk = atk;
}

public String getHp() {
    return hp;
}

public void setHp(String hp) {
    this.hp = hp;
}

public String getDef() {
    return def;
}

public void setDef(String def) {
    this.def = def;
}
```

}

estes são os metodos que usei:

```
   
    @Override
    public void salvar(Cards cards) {
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.persist(cards);
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
    }


    @Override
    public Specs find (Long id) {
        return manager.find(Specs.class,id);
    }
```

por fim a operação que estou tentando fazer tentando pegar uma linha que esta inserida na tabela Specs, e salvar ela na tabela Cards, mas pra isso eu preciso conseguir alterar o atributo String cardName antes:

```
public void teste(){
    DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) tableCards.getModel();
    modelo.setNumRows(0);
```

//
//
Specs specs = spec.find(Long.valueOf(19));

```
            textId.setText("");
            
            specs.setCardName(textId.getText());
            
            
            modelo.addRow(new Object[]{
                specs.getId(),    
                specs.getCardName(),
                specs.getAtk(),
                specs.getDef(),
                specs.getHp(),             
            });
```

//
spec.find(Long.valueOf(2));

```
            cartas.setCardName(specs.getCardName());
            cartas.setAtk(specs.getAtk());
            cartas.setDef(specs.getDef());
            cartas.setHp(specs.getHp());

            System.out.println(specs.getCardName());
            System.out.println(specs.getAtk());
            System.out.println(specs.getDef());
            System.out.println(specs.getHp());
           carta.salvar(cartas);
}
```

Comment: poste o seu código por inteiro, suas classes e o resto da operação que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Acabei de editar e coloquei o codigo

Comment: pesquisando a respeito parece que você precisa colocar isso nas anotações de relacionamento exemplo: `@ManyToMany(mappedBy=”admin”, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)`. Outra coisa aparece algum outro erro no console quando você tenta salvar? Se sim, atualize a pergunta com ele